# CSS HTML5 DIV Align Everything in Middle

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I can not figure out how to align the Month in Middle of the Arrows.
The i class is font awesome.
I have tried margin:auto, padding-top/padding bottom, line height etc. This should be easy.
But it always ends up on the bottom.

div needs the style code...

```
 <div>
 <i class="fa fa-caret-left" style="font-size:35px"></i>
  NOVEMBER 2020 
 <i class="fa fa-caret-Right" style="font-size:35px"></i>
 </div>
```

Comment: text-align:center should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use flexbox CSS.

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black; 
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <i class="fa fa-caret-left" style="font-size:35px">-</i>
  NOVEMBER 2020 
 <i class="fa fa-caret-Right" style="font-size:35px">+</i>
 </div>
```

Comment: Works for text thx - but I need 250px width centered on page. Align center doesn't work

Comment: can you please add an image of expected behaviour?

Comment: margin auto works

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you just want the text in the middle? If so, just create a class within your div and use the below CSS.

HTML

```
  <div class = "sample">
 <i class="fa fa-caret-left" style="font-size:35px"></i>
  NOVEMBER 2020 
 <i class=" fa fa-caret-Right" style="font-size:35px"></i>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
  .sample {
   margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

Comment: Month not aligned middle